# Losing connection on my main router when unplugging the secondary router's ethernet cable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I have two routers. One is my main router which has internet connection. The second router is connected to it with an Ethernet cable to extend connections in my house (LAN to LAN), as for the settings I didn't change the factory settings of the secondary router I plugged it directly and started using it, I have the DHCP enabled on my main router. Sometimes I want to unplug the secondary router and use only the first one, but every time I do it I lose internet connection (ADSL light just flashing and there is no light on internet) in my main router.

Why is that?

Comment: How are your routers set up? Which one is the DHCP server (or both)? Is the ethernet cable connected LAN-to-WAN or LAN-to-LAN?

Comment: Should not happen. Make sure LAN to LAN for the routers. Make sure only one DHCP server for the two routers.

Comment: Also (should have mentioned this), make sure only the Main Router is the DHCP server, not the secondary router.

Comment: Welcome to the community :) Daisy-chaining 2 home routers isn't really a good idea in the first place, why is a bit long explanation. What exactly makes you think your router loses the Internet connection, not just your wireless client? Please edit your question to add new info and clarifications instead of answering with a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a beginner in networking I don't know much. I edited the question and added as much information as I know I hope that helps